# hiding list items and show new li on click, but now I always need to have an empty li to "hide" them all

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a script that checks an li list and will show the first, with every click it will show the next li.

The problem is with this script, I have to add an empty li to "hide" all of them, is there a way to work around this, with this script?

```
    $('#test-div2 ul li').hide().filter(':lt(1)').show();
$('#hint-1').click(function(){
   $eL = $('#test-div2 ul li').filter(":visible");
$("#test-div2 ul").find("#test-div2 ul li").hide().next().show();
    if($eL.next().length>0){
              $eL.next().show();
          }
});
```

This is the html:

```
 <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li>hint 1</li>
    <li>hint 2</li>
    <li>hint 3</li>
    <li>hint 4</li>
    <li>hint 5</li>
    <li>hint 6</li>
    <li>hint 7</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: you could use a `button` outside of the `ul` instead of a `li`

Comment: what do you mean? I'm using a button to trigger it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just making the container `div` the thing to click to get a hint and cleaning up your JQuery a bit?

```js
$('#hints li').hide();
$('#test-div2').click(function(){
   $eL = $('#hints li').filter(":visible");
   $("#hints li:first-child").show();
   if($eL.next().length > 0){
     $eL.next().show();
   }
});
```

```css
#test-div2 {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <ul id="hints">
    <li>hint 1</li>
    <li>hint 2</li>
    <li>hint 3</li>
    <li>hint 4</li>
    <li>hint 5</li>
    <li>hint 6</li>
    <li>hint 7</li>
  </ul>
  
<div id="test-div2">Show hint</div>
```

Comment: Love your idea, but I need the hint to come elsewhere.. so it's not possible to have the div click there :-(.

Comment: @baswijdenesdotcom The hints (and/or) what you want to trigger them can be anywhere you want them to be. That's a styling issue.

Comment: @baswijdenesdotcom I have updated the answer to "disconnect" the `div` from the hints. Now, you can put the `div` anywhere you want.

Comment: Whelp you're right sorry. Took a look at your script the wrong way. It works perfectly!! thank you so much :-)